# How to get id from DataGridView where id columns is not presented in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, windows-forms-core

I have a DataGridView and I did not take an id column from database like below picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsQyj.png

And my database table looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp2vu.png

Now, I want to get id form selected row of DataGridView. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you viewing the table with the feature datasource of Datagridview ?

Comment: I am getting data from database using SQLiteDataAdapter and filling this data into DataTable. after filling the DataTable, I provided this DataTable as a DataSource to DataGridView.

Comment: İ guess you can get id column with these 2 columns. And hide ID column when u show data to user.

Comment: If I get id column from database and hide it during runtime, so how can I get this id using datagridview 0 column? even id is hidden. Is 0 column of id still there on backend?

Comment: yeah if u try to access datagridview.rows[i].cells[0].value . You get ID value

Comment: Try it if u fail. I can help u as i can

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).